# Spin precession for Rabi oscillations : interpretation with magnetic field in rotating frame

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance, rabi-model

**The model considered**

Consider an atom modeled by a two level system of energy $\hbar \omega$. We assume this atom is interacting with an electric field through electric-dipole interaction.

The full Hamiltonian is thus this one ($|e\rangle$ is the excited state and $|g\rangle$ the ground one):

$$ H = \hbar \omega_0 |e\rangle \langle e | -\mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{E_0} \cos(\omega_L t) \, .$$

We can rewrite it as

$$ H = \frac{\hbar \omega}{2} \mathbb{1} + \hbar \omega_0 S_z -2 \hbar \Omega_1 \cos(\omega_L t) S_x $$

where $S_i = \sigma_i/2$ ($\sigma_i$ is the i$^\text{th}$ Pauli matrix), $\Omega_1 = \langle e|\mathbf{d}|g\rangle \cdot \mathbf{E_0}=\langle g|\mathbf{d}|e\rangle . \mathbf{E_0}$ (I assumed for simplicity that the two dipole elements are positive numbers).

**The analogy with a spin-magnetic field interaction**

This Hamiltonian, if we put away the energy constant $\frac{\hbar \omega}{2}$ can be interpreted as a spin interacting with the magnetic field via $H=-\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{S}$ where $[1]$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{B} &= \mathbf{B_0} + \mathbf{B_1} \\
\mathbf{B_0} &= \hbar \omega_0 \mathbf{U_z}\\
\mathbf{B_1} &= 2 \hbar \Omega_1 \cos(\omega_L t) \mathbf{U_x}=\hbar \Omega_1 \mathbf{U_+}+\hbar \Omega_1 \mathbf{U_-}
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{U_+}$ is a unitary vector rotating around the z-axis at frequency $\omega_L$ and $\mathbf{U_-}$ rotated in the opposite direction at the same frequency.

What we usually do in quantum mechanics is to go in the interacting picture, which mean to go in the rotating frame at frequency $\omega_L$ around z-axis.

In this frame, the magnetic field $\hbar \Omega_1 \mathbf{U_+}$ is now constant, $\hbar \Omega_1 \mathbf{U_-}$ turns at frequency $2 \omega_L$ I will neglect the latter corresponding to the rotating wave approximation.

**Result of the model from a purely quantum mechanical treatment**

The "real" quantum mechanical treatment would tell me that the rotating frame Hamiltonian is now

$$H=\hbar (\omega-\omega_L) S_z - \hbar \Omega_1 S_x \, .$$

**Result of the model with the spin-magnetic field analogy**

However, using this magnetic field vision, I would end up with

$$H=\hbar \omega S_z - \hbar \Omega_1 S_x \, .$$

Indeed, the field $\mathbf{B_0}$ doesn't change with this rotation because I do a rotation around its axis. And as I only kept the part of $\mathbf{B_1}$ that rotates in the counter-clockwise direction, $\mathbf{B_1}$ is now constant in this frame $[2]$.

**My question**

Where is the problem in the "magnetic field" vision of it? Why doesn't the analogy seem to work here?

---

$[1]$: My magnetic field are not in SI dimensions here, you can add an appropriate dimensional constant if you wish.

$[2]$: Actually it wouldn't surprise me if $B_0$ would change in the rotating frame, but here http://puhep1.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/rotatingEM.pdf it seems that the magnetic field should stay the same.

Comment: what is the unitary transformation to go to the rotating frame in each version?

Comment: @IamAStudent In the Q.M treatment we swich to interacting picture through $U=e^{+\frac{i}{ \hbar} \hbar \omega_L |e\rangle \langle e|}$. Indeed we have rewritten the Hamiltonian as : $H=\hbar \omega_L |e\rangle \langle e| + \hbar (\omega_0 - \omega_L) |e\rangle \langle e| -d.E_0 cos(\omega t)$. Thus we have $|\psi\rangle \rightarrow |\psi_I\rangle = U |\psi\rangle$. In the analogy we don't really apply any unitary transformation. We just rewrite the "analogy" magnetic field in the rotating frame at frequency $\omega_L$ and it gives us our new Hamiltonian.

Comment: well, I don't think that is true. Your operator $S$ in the Zeeman Hamiltonian $-S \cdot B$ will be affected by the same kind of unitary transformation. Pauli matrices span two-level system Hamiltonians, so there is no reason the magnetic dipole and B-field analogy should behave somewhat different from the actual two-level sytem.

Comment: @IamAStudent I agree and this is my question : why do I end up with two different results ? Where is my mistake in the analogy ?

Comment: I believe the mistake is that your claim that the magnetic field analogy doesn't involve unitary transformation.

Comment: @IamAStudent well for me the unitary transformation is hidden in the fact the magnetic field changes. In in a frame $R$ I have $H=-B.S$, then if I go in the rotating frame $R'$, the Hamiltonian in this frame will be $H'=-B'.S$ (where $B'$ is the magnetic field in $R'$). But doing this doesn't give the same result as the full Q.M treatment, which is weird.

Comment: @IamAStudent It doesn't give the good result because of the $U_z$ component of the field that should change to have the good result. But from what I read, rotating around an axis $z$ doesn't change the $z$ component of a magnetic field (which for me is weird but it is what I read in the link I added). I found it weird because in a rotating frame, I would see fixed charged now moving so I wouldn't be surprized in $B_z$ changes.

Comment: Okay, in the lab frame, $H = -B \cdot S = -B_z \cdot S_z - B_x (t) \cdot S_x$. When you do unitary transformation + rotating wave approximation to remove time dependence in the operator $-B_x (t) \cdot S_x$, you get an effective field B'_z in the rotating frame, and the total z-component of your B-field is proportional to the detuning from resonance. When you say "unitary transformation is hidden in the fact that B-field changes" that doesn't really mean anything. My emphasis is that to removing time-dependence in the operator $-B_x (t) \cdot S_x $ is just like how you showed for the two-level

Comment: What is a "unitary vector"?

Comment: *"Indeed, the field $\mathbf{B}_0$ doesn't change with this rotation because I do a rotation around its axis."* That's your mistake: that statement is false. Intuitively you can see that it's false because $\mathbf{B}_0$ sets the precession frequency of the spin and if you go into a rotating frame then the precession frequency changes.

Answer (score 1):

The rotating coordinate system method is equally applicable to classical and quantum-mechanical systems.

In the classical formulation the equation of motion of the system in a stationary coordinate system is
$$d \vec J / dt = \vec \mu \times \vec B = \gamma \vec J \times \vec B$$
where:
$\vec \mu = \gamma \vec J$ magnetic moment.
$\vec J$ angular momentum.
$\gamma$ gyromagnetic ratio.
$\vec B$ magnetic field.

In a rotating coordinate system with angular velocity $\vec \omega$, we have
$$d \vec J / dt = \partial \vec J / \partial t + \vec \omega \times \vec J$$
where $\vec J$ on both sides is the angular momentum measured in the stationary frame while $\partial \vec J / \partial t$ measures the change of $\vec J$ in the rotating frame.
Rearranging
$$\partial \vec J / \partial t = \gamma \vec J \times \vec B_{rotating}$$
where $\vec B_{rotating} = \vec B + \vec \omega / \gamma.$

In most of the cases $\vec B$ is given by a constant field $\vec B_0$ plus a (usually much weaker) $\vec B_1$ field perpendicular to $\vec B_0$ and rotating with angular velocity $- \omega$. In a coordinate system rotating with $\vec B_1$ both the fields are constant, so the axes of the rotating system can be chosen such that
$$\vec B_0 = B_0 \vec k$$
$$\vec B_1 = B_1 \vec i$$
$$\vec \omega = - \omega \vec k$$
Then , in the rotating coordinate system
$$\vec B_{rotating} = (B_0 - \omega / \gamma) \vec k + B_1 \vec i.$$

The Hamiltonian in the rotating coordinate system is
$$H_{rotating} = -\vec \mu \cdot \vec B_{rotating} = -\gamma \vec J \cdot ((B_0 - \omega / \gamma) \vec k + B_1 \vec i)$$
If $$\vec J = J_x \vec i + J_y \vec j + J_z \vec k,$$ we have
$$H_{rotating} = -(\gamma B_0 - \omega) J_z - \gamma B_1 J_x.$$

As you can read the classical treatment shows formally identical to the quantum mechanical treatment.

Note: In my demonstration $\omega$ corresponds to $\omega_L$ in your post.